# VSCode loads old DLL (System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt) on startup

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, microsoft-graph-api, pnp.powershell

i am developing a powershell cmdlet with microsoft.graph and pnp.powershell. When vscode starts an older version of the dll is loaded by microsoft.graph.authentication. PnP.powershell needs a newer version of this dll and cannot load it because the older version is already loaded. If I start my script fast enough (press F5 during the VSCode initial script loading), the newer dll is loaded first by PnP. So it seems that something in VSCode is reloading via graph and thereby loading the dll into memory. I have already deactivated all possible extensions, except for powershell and the language pack. Has anyone of you ever had such a problem and knows a solution or a way how I can find out who is loading the old dll?
dll version loaded by microsoft.graph.authentication: 5.6.0.61018 (2019)
needed dll version by pnp.powershell: 6.27.0.40215 (2023)
I'm using powershell 7.
Thank you for your help.

i try to disable extensions except powershell 2023.6.0 and german language pack
i expect to start VSCode wait some time (2 minutes) connect to for example sharepoint with pnp.powershell (connect-pnponline) and get no error that these dll could not be loaded.